# How to execute a statement which was a string initially

Tags: python, string, command, execute

My question is about how to make the compiler treats my string as an executable statement, consider my string mystr='1+2+3', now the question is what's the code to put in function `func` so when I execute the following command `func(mystr)` I get 6 on my screen.

Comment: use `eval(mystr)`

Comment: Solved, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval(mystr)`.

[Documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Answer (score 3):

Using [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for more than just expression strings:

```
def func(mystr):
    exec(mystr)

func("mystr='1+2+3';print(mystr)")
```

Comment: What's the difference between eval() and exec()?

Comment: @franciscosollima [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) take any Python code (sentences) while [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) just expressions. The doc linked is clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval(mystr).

```
 print eval('1+2+3')
```

gives you 6